# Why does Ender Wiggin win all the time if he is always outnumbered, weaker, and physically/materially inferior?

Tags: enders-game

Why does Ender Wiggin win all the time? He is always outmatched, and yet he always wins. His strategy seems to be based on completely destroying the opponent, but that strategy is usually used by those who have the advantage. How does Ender win even when he is at a disadvantage, especially when he fights like someone who has the advantage?

Comment: Completely destroying the opponent is NOT a strategy of the strongest, it is in fact a strategy of the weak.  Totally wiping out the weak is unnecessary because they are weak, and so they can be USED and not destroyed.  They aren't a threat.  Totally destroying your opponent is a way of bluffing and/or deterring attacks -- i.e. "you might win against me, but you might not, and if you don't, you will be destroyed".  The strong don't need to do this, because they (and everyone else) knows they **will** win.  The more certain this is, the less there is any reason to deter an attack.

Comment: Destroying the opponent is a strategy to *avoid* the next fight; it's not a strategy or tactic for winning the *current* fight, just an available option as the *result* of winning.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's because he's a rare tactical genius who can come up with new schemes that are within the given rules, but are tactically novel, and he's ruthless due to his past abuse situation with Peter, which has rendered him always ready to fight, and desperate to win.

Comment: Most notably, during Battle School, he introduced [mission-type tactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission-type_tactics) in an environment dominated by top-down command.  (Mission-type tactics are far more flexible than top-down command, but require subordinates that are far more skilled -- in Battle School terms, his toon second-in-commands need to be skilled enough to operate as army commanders.)

Comment: And he also willing to destroy his opponent so that he would never have to fight the same fight twice (something that a lot of opponents wouldn't do)

Comment: He loathes his brother but loves his sister. Don't they use her as a carrot on a stick at some point? This entire family is *by-design* for like the last 40y. "He's a genetically-engineered genius super-soldier that has been raised to fear failure". He was bred to be the chosen one; surely there's people pulling strings left and right for him, which ever way they *need* to be pulled.

Comment: SPOILER!: @Mark: Not to forget that a later book, "Ender's Shadow" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Shadow), reveals that the second-in-commands *as well as the soldiers* of his toon were handpicked to match his genius. IIRC, several statements by Ender in the first book hint that Ender already guessed that fact. (E.g. once he complains that the battle school leaders first stacked the cards for him, only to stack the cards against him again with unfair game scenarios.)

Answer (score 9):

The [blurb](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Ender-s-Game-The-Ender-Quintet-Pre-Owned-Other-0812550706-9780812550702-Orson-Scott-Card/727577677) for the novel basically tells you everything that you need to know about Ender. He's a genetically-engineered genius super-soldier that has been raised to fear failure, to the point where he is willing to 'think the unthinkable' in order to win; Studying his enemy's tactics, bending the rules of combat to their breaking point, and offering his opponents (human and alien) unimagined levels of violence.

> In order to develop a secure defense against a hostile alien race's
> next attack, **government agencies breed child geniuses and train them
> as soldiers. A brilliant young boy, Andrew "Ender" Wiggin lives with
> his kind but distant parents, his sadistic brother Peter, and the
> person he loves more than anyone else, his sister Valentine. Peter and
> Valentine were candidates for the soldier-training program but didn't
> make the cut--young Ender is the Wiggin drafted to the orbiting Battle
> School for rigorous military training. Ender's skills make him a
> leader in school and respected in the Battle Room, where children play
> at mock battles in zero gravity.**
>
> Is Ender the general Earth needs? But **Ender is not the only result of the genetic experiments.** The war with the Buggers has been raging for a hundred years, and the quest for the perfect general has been underway for almost as long. Ender's two older siblings are every bit as unusual as he is, but in very different ways. Between the three of them lie the abilities to remake a world. If the world survives, that is.

Comment: Perhaps that blurb writer did not read the book very carefully.

Comment: @GEdgar - It seems a fairly good description to me

Comment: Wasn't the ability to envision, extrapolate and then traverse a three dimensional battle field the big ah-ha moment? That's about the only thing that's important in the like first 100 pages. He 'gets' it almost immediately, or is the first to. *Up is down.*

Comment: "Ender's [training] make him a leader" ... not *skills*. They continually stack the deck against him until he learns how to beat a stacked deck.

Comment: @Mazura Reminds me of how Day9 spoke about practicing StarCraft with a partner who always map-hacked. He said what you do is execute a strategy so well that they can't stop it even when they know it's coming. Not rely on surprises or unexpected tactics. And that's in the real world. Ender takes advantage unexpected tricks and blind spots to get his victories.

Comment: @Mazura All the students were being trained. Ender had the *skill* to best make use of the training.